# Candle.exe not running for specific project while building wix solution

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I have the wix 3.9 solution in Visual Studio. It has three similar wix setup projects. They use same Product.wxs, but they differ in preprocessor variables from each other.
When I build each project separately candle.exe is running before light.exe. So preprocessor variables are processed and msi-files are correct. But when I build whole solution one of my projects is building without candle.exe with light.exe only. So for that project preprocessor variables ignored. As result msi is incorrect.
This project was added to solution later than other.
Can you tell me why candle.exe is not runing while solution build? Maybe there is some magic checkbox for this purpose?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem. Two projects were in the same directory. While solution was building first project Product.wxs was handled by candle.exe and as a result Product.wixobj file was generated. Then second project was bulding wix checked that Product.wixobj has already existed and other files had not changed since Product.wixobj have compiled.
So candle.exe step was skipped.